# Is it possible to automatically create a .install file for a module?

Tags: 7, installation

I have a content type that I want to install as part of a module or install profile. Is there anyway to automatically create all the `field_create_field` and `field_create_instances` code that would go in `hook_install` or do I have to do all that manually?

Is there any other way to capture the settings of a content type so I can migrate it and include it in an install profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just the field and field instances that you want converted ready for an install file (i.e. if Features is too overkill for you or you don't want the extra dependency), then [Field Inspector](https://drupal.org/project/field_inspector) will give you all the code you need for creating your fields in code.

> Field inspector provides an administrative user interface for the
>   Field Info API. This allows users to select what information,
>   formatting, and fields they would like to see, and provides output in
>   a manner that can be copied into a module, or install profile into a
>   hook_install, or hook_update_N function.

Comment: Last updated ~2011 and only 31 sites using it - is it really stable & usable now?

Comment: Yeah - it's fine. I'd ignore the stats as it's a development level module. Those stats are also pretty flawed in that they only show modules for sites that have Update Manager enabled.

Comment: @molot As an example: Chaos Tools reports 489,224 D7 installs.  But realistically, it has to be on almost every site (cTools really is the *other* Drupal core in my opinion) - so those stats are relatively meaningless :)

Comment: I'm not arguing, just asking. And I'd say above about 1000 reported installs we can pretty much trust at least major bugs are identified, below only experience can help. I'm willing to trust your experience with it once you confirmed you have it ;)

Comment: @Mołot I didn't think you were arguing - I just wanted to back up my statement with a fact :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module:

> The features module enables the capture and management of features in Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken together satisfy a certain use-case.
>
> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal module except that it declares its components (e.g. views, contexts, CCK fields, etc.) in its .info file so that it can be checked, updated, or reverted programmatically.

Comment: Or (even better IMO) [Configuration Management](https://drupal.org/project/configuration)

Comment: Hi clive. Is it possible to programmatically include an exported configuration from configuration module into an install profile?

Comment: @Clive I'm shy to suggest anything less stable than beta to people I don't know ;) Configuration Management looks like just as good or better in this case, but we don't know what *else* OP would want to pack. If other configurations, it's better. If some helper modules for his content type, Features wins. And so on. Feel free and invited to edit this into my answer, or post your answer for me to upvote ;)

Comment: @AndrewWelch Hmmm probably not actually, it'd need to be wrapped up in a module. In which case Features would actually make more sense as it'll create that module for you

Comment: @Clive I'm printing/framing this comment ;-)

Comment: @Mołot It's a good module, the admin interface gets a bit sluggish when there's a lot of config (same as features), it's really a cut down version of the same. I've been using it for ages and haven't had any problems. Yet...

Comment: @Chapabu No-one will believe you...